# React dropdown only show value if clicked on specific data using e.target?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to make this accordion and right now it maps through my data and essentially shows all the dropdown values when I click on my `h1`, but I only want it to show the dropdown for the specific `h1` I clicked and not display the entire values

```
    const Accordion = () => {
      const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

      const toggle = e => {
        if (e.target) {
          setClicked(!clicked);
        }

        console.log(e.target);
      };

      return (
        <div>
          {Data.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <h1 onClick={e => toggle(e)}>{item.question}</h1>
                {clicked ? (
                  <div>
                    <p>{item.answer}</p>
                  </div>
                ) : null}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

My toggle function shows the correct e.target value of the h1 I clicked on, but I don't know how to only display that `h1` value when I click on it instead of showing all `h1's` values

Here is my data file

```
           export const Data = [
        {
          question: 'What 1?',
          answer: 'answer 1'
        },
        {
          question: 'What 2',
          answer: 'answer 2'
        },
        {
          question: 'What 3?',
          answer: 'answer 3'
        }
      ];
```

How would I refactor my code to only show question 1 and answer 1, vs showing all questions and answers on click?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to a separate component with its own state and use that for each accordion item.

```js
const AccordionItem = (props) => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 onClick={() => setClicked(! clicked)}>{props.question}</h1>
      {clicked && (
        <div>
          <p>{item.answer}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const Accordion = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Data.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <AccordionItem
            key={index}
            question={item.question}
            answer={item.answer}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: that would end up writing extra code when I have to pass each separate component in my app.js, so I'd have like 10 <Accordions /> vs. just mapping through a data file

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the clicked question in state rather than just whether something was clicked or not. E.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-night-4uulw?file=/src/App.js

```
const Data = [
    {
        question: 'What 1?',
        answer: 'answer 1',
    },
    {
        question: 'What 2',
        answer: 'answer 2',
    },
    {
        question: 'What 3?',
        answer: 'answer 3',
    },
];

const Accordion = () => {
    const [activeQn, setActiveQn] = useState(null);

  const toggle = ( index ) => {
    // If the clicked qn is already active, then collapse it
    if ( activeQn === index ) {
      return setActiveQn(null)
    } 
    // Otherwise show the answer to the clicked qn
    setActiveQn(index)
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {Data.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <h1 onClick={() => toggle(index)}>{item.question}</h1>
                        {activeQn === index ? (
                            <div>
                                <p>{item.answer}</p>
                            </div>
                        ) : null}
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

That way, only the clicked answer will show and if the user wishes to collapse the answer, that can also be done.

Comment: why did you add an underscore for the e? (_e)

Comment: I should have just omitted the event argument entirely (have edited now). The underscore is just the rules I have set up so that when an argument is not used (e.g. an event argument when other args are also present), I don't get a warning for unused args.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track which div has been clicked . You can do that assigning `id` in your data like this:

```
const Data = [
  {
    question: "What 1?",
    answer: "answer 1",
    id: 0
  },
  {
    question: "What 2",
    answer: "answer 2",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    question: "What 3?",
    answer: "answer 3",
    id: 2
  }
];
```

Then send this id on `toggle` method and check if id is equal to selected one or not like this:

```
const toggle = (e, id) => {
    if (e.target) {
      setSelected(id === selected ? null : id); //selected and id are same it means close the toggle
    }

    console.log(e.target);
  };
```

and inside render check like this:

```
{selected === item.id ? (
              <div>
                <p>{item.answer}</p>
              </div>
            ) : null}
```

Here is full demo and code: https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-accordian-eplpw